# How to use sequelize (SQL Server) to find data that are in radius/polygon using lat/long coordinates?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have table like this, in which coordinates are stored:

[image]

I want to have some king of query to find all data that are inside radius (or polygon)

```
await models.AddressAddress
        .findAll({
            raw: true,
            limit: 1,
            where: { ///is in radius/polygon}
        })
```

Help please. I can't find any data examples or info